# Sticky menu issue with ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, ipad

I have created custom menu and apply as sticky menu and I when user click to any particulate anchor link, It will scroll to that section (Like Up and Down).

Now In desktop version page scroll is working smoothly with sticky menu but when I cheeked In iPad mini or iPad 2, sticky menu is vibrating. I don't know how to fix this kind of issue.

Check this [Demo](http://goo.gl/BJZrbi) Link

I will appreciate If someone help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using? Otherwise its a rather arduous task sifting through your site's JS and CSS.

Comment: Device's support of 'position:fixed' is [shaky at best](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/), as it is a property that can lead to users getting trapped on screen. You also appear to be using jQuery to animate, which will run slower on devices, often causing clunky animations. Have you tried using CSS3 animations instead? Faster, smoother, lighter :)

Answer (score 0):

Check these jQuery plugins. They could help you to create a complete menu with ease. These are just two of many you can find.

http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/ **HC-Sticky**

http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/ **Smint**

Maybe it could help you!

Comment: In order to keep answers complete and self-contained please include all relevant information in the answer.

Comment: @EWit I added details.